# Hyperlinks can be added by low reputation users via editing

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, new-users

In its efforts to prevent spamming and content plagiarism, Stack Overflow limits the number of hyperlinks for a user to 2 (*More links require 10 or more reputation*).

I was able to overcome this limitation by first posting an answer, then editing it to include more hyperlinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14065180/1369235) then looking at [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14065180/revisions) it was not [you who added hyperlinks as a hyperlink.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14065180/2) You added extra hyperlinks as a *code*/

Comment: But then later on i was able to modify CODE to HYPERLINKS

Comment: @UmeshABhat - Because you got +1 vote on that answer and you earned [Remove new user restrictions privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user)

Comment: Ah, ok my bad..